# How to change the starting order number for Commerce 2?

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to change the initial order number for my new Commerce store to 777 instead of 1.

For Drupal 7, [there is an explanation here](https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/3172/how-can-i-change-starting-order-number), but I know the Commerce architecture has changed a lot.

I'm using Drupal 8.4 and Commerce 2.1.

The basic approach described is to use a sql query to adjust `AUTO_INCREMENT` for the order table-- is that still the recommended approach in Commerce 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command in the given explanation on my commerce 2 projects and it worked without any problems. So I am pretty sure you can't do anything wrong with this command.